# Cant' get my own logs from Java app to show up in Google StackDriver logs

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I have a basic "hello world" level webapp setup on Google AppEngine. I can't figure out how to get logs to show up in StackDriver.

I realized that I had to enable billing to get any logs to show up. I now see some logs from Spring initialization code when I make the first request to a newly deployed app, but I still don't see any of my custom logs.

I have an endpoint with the following code:

```
private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(IndexController.class.getName());

LOG.info("Rendering index page");
System.out.println("Writing to system out");
System.err.println("Writing to system err");
```

None of those show up in StackDriver.

This is my appengine-web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
    <application>myapp</application>
    <version>1</version>
    <runtime>java8</runtime>
    <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>
    <system-properties>
        <property name="java.util.logging.config.file" value="WEB-INF/logging.properties"/>
    </system-properties>
</appengine-web-app>
```

And this is my WEB-INF/logging.properties file:

```
.level = INFO
```

Comment: Have you digged deeper in the requests? I have just tried that, and there is no specific entry in the Logs, but if you have a look inside the request, at the bottom of the log dropdown menu, I see the logging information.

Comment: Did you make any traction on this? I am having the same issue and posted another question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48195200/spring-boot-app-engine-log-messages-not-showing.