# Spring Boot App Engine log messages not showing

Tags: google-app-engine, spring-boot, logging

I have a Spring Boot application that I am deploying to an App Engine standard environment using Java 8. I cannot seem to get log messages to show in the log viewer in my cloud console. I do have other logs working such as the endpoint being hit.

logging.properties:

```
.level = FINEST
```

appengine-web.xml:

```xml
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
    <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>
    <runtime>java8</runtime>
    <service>logging-service</service>

    <system-properties>
        <property name="java.util.logging.config.file" value="WEB-INF/logging.properties"/>
    </system-properties>
</appengine-web-app>
```

Spring Controller:

```java
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import static org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod.GET;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/log")
public class LogSubscription {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(LogSubscription.class.getName());

    @RequestMapping(method = GET)
    public String logSomething() {
        log.log(Level.INFO, "Should see this in the console");
        log.log(Level.SEVERE, "This is severe");
        log.info("Normal Log Message");

        return "Should log successfully";
    }
}
```

Logging to the console works perfectly fine when I run locally. I just can't see the logs in the web console. I can see the GET request but not the logging in it. I am attaching a screenshot of my log.

[image: Cloud Log]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was finally able to find a solution. You must add the following to the build.gradle file:

```
configurations {
    compile.exclude group: "org.slf4j", module: "jul-to-slf4j"
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what they recommend [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/getting-started-java/tree/master/appengine-standard-java8/springboot-appengine-standard#exclude-jul-to-slf4j-bridge).